# make pause between drawing two draws

Tags: android, multithreading, drawing, android-canvas, draw

I want to make a pause between drawing two draws. I've tried `Thread.sleep`, handlers, `asyncTask` and got same result - when activity starts up I must wait for a time that I set to see the first draw, only when I call same method (test) again, I see second draw instead of seeing first draw again. There's my code:

```
public void test(){
button.setClickable(false);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
view.setFromAtoB(true);
view.invalidate();
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        view.setMoveAB(true);
        view.postInvalidate();
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        button.setClickable(true);           
    }
};
task.execute((Void[])null);
```

Where's the problem? Why can't I see some kind of harmony, first draw, pause, second draw? :) Maybe I've blocked UI thread. For drawing I use canvas. In `onDraw` method I make some calculations and call `drawRodsAndDiscs` method:

```
private void drawRodsAndDiscs(Canvas canvas){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    drawRods(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    for (Rect disc : discs) {
        canvas.drawRect(disc, paint);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this code for your problem.
When the timer is finished it is automagically restarted.
Try this:

```
private boolean running = false;
private Handler handler;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    handler = new Handler(this.getMainLooper()); //Run it in MainLooper
    this.handler.postDelayed(this.counterThread, 200); //Start timer in 200ms
}

private Thread counterThread = new Thread() {
public void run() {
        if (isRunning()) {
            return;
        }
        setRunning(true);

// 10minute until finish, 200ms between ticks
        CountDownTimer ct = new CountDownTimer(10 * 60 * 1000, 200) {

            public void onFinish() {
                setRunning(false);
            }

            public void onTick(long time) {
                    //Do your shitznaz
            }
        };
        ct.start();
    }
};

protected boolean isRunning() {
    return this.running;
}
protected void setRunning(boolean b) {
    this.running = b;
    if (!b) {
        // Reset timer
        this.handler.postDelayed(this.counterThread, 200); //Restarts the timer in 200ms
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a simple `CountDownTimer` instead of Thread.sleep(int miliseconds);

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) :

Answer (score 0):

For a simple one-off delay you can use a `Handler` instead:

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {                
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setMoveAB(true);
                view.invalidate();
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                button.setClickable(true); 
            }
        }, 2000);
```